# WiFi or Bluetooth not working in ubuntu 16.04 LTS (dual boot)

Tags: networking, dual-boot, bluetooth

My Sys Spec: Dell-Laptop (Inspiron 15 (3000 series)) Os : Window 10(Original with Laptop) , Ubuntu-16.04(Dual Boot)

After installing ubuntu, I am unable to see Wifi Connections and unable to connect to Wifi (Wireless) Connections. Also i am unable to connect any bluetooth device. However I am able to connect through Wired (LAN) Connections

This issue is not there in Window-10. Its working fine in Windows-10.

Can anyone help me on this please ?

Result of lshw -C network
       *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ab200000-ab207fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: enp7s0
       version: 07
       serial: 20:47:47:59:41:af
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:46 ioport:4000(size=256)
memory:ab100000-ab100fff
memory:d2100000-d2103fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: enp0s29u1u1
       serial: fa:45:4c:26:cc:b0
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.198 link=yes multicast=yes

Result of rfkill list --
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

Comment: Edit your post and show us the command and result of `sudo lshw -C network`. Then we might be able to begin solving.

Comment: That is most likely an issue of missing device drivers. Try update/install drivers through wired connection.